# Javascript webpage stop functioning, unresponsive/crashes

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm having an issue with a Javascript assignment task. Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is a "screensaver" design loop using html5 canvas. When a button is clicked in html, it runs a function that uses random number generation to decide on a shape, location of the shape, shape fill colour and shape stroke style, draws the shape and then loops back around again. The issue I'm currently having is when the button is clicked, the page (I'm using both chrome and firefox) crashes. I understood that this may be because of the loop that I am using, so in response I put a 1.5 second delay on the function- however it still won't function. Any advice on how to improve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

(I tried indenting code by 4 spaces, sorry wouldn't work for some reason..?)

HTML:

```html
<button onclick="Screensaver()">Screensaver</button><br>
<div id="Screensaver">
    <br><button onclick="screenstart()">Start Screensaver</button><br>
    <br><button onclick="screenstop()">Stop Screensaver</button>
</div><br>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="600" style="border:1px solid #47bfff;">
</canvas>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,canvas.width,0);
//screensaver variables
var loop = 0;
var shapenum = 0;
var fillnum = 0;
var stylenum = 0;
var SS = document.getElementById("Screensaver");
//rectangle
var rectx1 = 0;
var recty1 = 0;
var rectx2 = 0;
var recty2 = 0;
//triangle
var trix = 0;
var triy = 0;
//circle
var circx = 0;
var circy = 0;
var circr = 0;
//radius calculation
var sct = 0;
var scb = 0;
var scl = 0;
var scr = 0;
var scmax = 0;
//SCREENSAVER FROM HERE
SS.style.display = "none";
function Screensaver() {
    if (SS.style.display === "" +
        "none") {
        SS.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        SS.style.display = "none";
    }
}
//loop
function screenstart(){
    loop = 1;
    while (loop = 1){
        setTimeout(screenloop(), 1500);
        screenloop();
    }
}
function screenstop(){
    loop = 0;
}

function screenloop(){
    randcal();
    ifstatements();
}
//just calculations from here on down
```

Comment: There is far too much code here, most people won't try to wade through it, you should try to cut it down to the minimal code which reproduces the problem. Having said that, I can see the source of the problem - the loop in `screenstart` is infinite, and freezes your browser. You should use `setInterval` to run `screenloop` every 1500 milliseconds, and check the value of `loop` inside that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the problem is in your `screenstart` function. There are actually quite a few things wrong in that, but the main one, which causes the crashing/freezing of your browser, is that the loop never actually ends. Javascript is single threaded, that is it can only do one thing at a time - and while the loop should stop when `loop` is 0 (or would if you'd correctly used `==` rather than `=`), this never happens because your code is stuck in a loop, executing `screenloop` continually (while also scheduling more and more calls to this function later, not that it can ever get to them).

There is a straightforward fix though. Cut down the function to just this:

```
function screenstart(){
    loop = 1;
    setInterval(screenloop, 1500);
}
```

And then do the following in `screenloop`:

```
function screenloop(){
    if (loop == 1) {
        randcal();
        ifstatements();
    }
}
```

The most important difference is that you simply schedule `screenloop` to run every 1.5 seconds, while allowing other events to happen, and other code to run if necessary, in between. Including the possibility of `loop` being set to 0. And every time `screenloop` runs, it checks this value, and only does its stuff if the value is 1.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, its given me a good insight into Javascript. My only problem now however is that for this task I need it to loop around and continue adding shapes until the user tells it to stop- With your suggestion it only adds one shape per button click, I'm assuming because of the if check- Do you know of a method to continually loop it that isn't like my original method? Thanks for your help

Comment: I confess I'm rather unsure as to how your code is supposed to work - but the `setInterval` in my suggestion should get `randcal` and `ifstatements` to run continually, every 1.5 seconds, until the `loop` variable changes value. Are you sure you changed your `setTimeout` (which only schedules the event once) to `setInterval` as above?

Comment: Ah thank you so much it was just a mistake in syntax, putting '()' after the function name in the interval

Answer (score 0):

Your current code basically spams the event loop with calls to `screenloop()`.

`setTimeout()` just schedules a call to that function in 1.5s, but does not hold the loop until then. So basically your loop here just fills up the event loop until the browser crashes.

```
function screenstart(){
    loop = 1;
    while (loop = 1){
        setTimeout(screenloop(), 1500);
        screenloop();
    }
}
```

For animations like yours you may want to look at [`requestAnimantionFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). On a very rough first attempt this could look like this (I did not look though all of your code, whether this actually will work. Depends on different factors, like how long each rendering loop takes etc):

```
let animationId;

function screenstart(){
  randcal();
  ifstatements(); 
  animationId = requestAnimationFrame(screenstart);
}

function screenstop(){
  cancelAnimationFrame( animationId );
}
```